# How do I add pre-set text in form for Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

I was watching this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=879&v=KGfZPP36QUI) to create a form in Angular 2 with validation, but I really want to know how this person included the beginning of the url in the input field already. I've followed his same code and can't get the "http://" section to show by default.

This is what I have

```
<label>Company URL <span class="required">*</span></label>
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="company.company_url" name="url" #url="ngModel" type="url" pattern="https?://.+" id="url" required maxlength="255">
<div *ngIf="companyErrors?.url" class="alert alert-field alert-danger">
    {{companyErrors.url}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `company.company_url` value had been initialized before component's first render. You may try to do an assignment on the component's constructor:

```
constructor(/*...*/) {
  // ...
  company.company_url = "http://";
}
```

or maybe better on `NgInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  // ...
  company.company_url = "http://";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be utilising `placeholder` attribute on your `input` tag.

Something like this

```
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="company.company_url" name="url" #url="ngModel" type="url" pattern="https?://.+" id="url" required maxlength="255" placeholder="http://">
```

would render the same effect.